# "Add Group Price" button not shown in magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

my problem is: the button "Add Group Price" is not shown in magento backend.

I have made some changes to database but not exactly sure where!

it's the normal magento backend:
[image: Magento normal Backend]

and here is my magento view:
[image: My magento backend viw]

as you see the button "Add Group Price" is not shown!!!

where should i fix?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a right-to-left language so the buttons are on the opposite side.

Although I don't speak the language, I'm going to say with 99.99999999% confidence that the button is this one:
[image]

Comment: no this is not that button adds row for tier prices as you see on the right side BUT i am looking for GROUP PRICES!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

is same as "Add group price(إضافة سعر المجموعة)"

good luck

Comment: no this is not that  button adds row for tier prices as you see on the right side

Comment: that button is realated to tier prices not GROUP PRICES!

Answer (score 0):

so, as i see you have attribute value set as required, but i dont see any red asterisk symbol (*) near to it. and actually i dont see on screenshot Group Price field either?? so all you need is:

there is no magic. i dont see what you have done exactly. But it looks like you did something wrong.

create an attribute

- name it Group Price with code group_price
- set to Display on product page
- Add it to your Attribute Set
- edit product and enter Group Price value
- then call it on product view

Comment: How can I call it on product view?